# Input field is not increasing width for mobile device screen HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form with an input field. Now on a laptop screen the width of the input takes up 30% of the screen which is correct.

However, what I want to do is that if the device is 600px in width or less (mobile device) then increase the width to 60%.

The problem is that it is not changing the width in the mobile device. Seems like it is taking up only 30% on the mobile device and not 60%. I am not sure what I am doing incorretly as I am using the @media tag based on research.

```
    <section id="marketing-email">
    <form class="marketing-email-form" method="post" action="https://metis-online.com/marketing-email.php">
    <div>
    <label for="email"><b>Be part of our mailing list to receive exclusive promotional offers on our courses and services:</b></label><br/>
    <input type="email" id="market-email" name="market-email" required placeholder="Email"/> 
    <button type="submit" class="marketing-btn">Send</button>
    </div>
        </form>
   </section>

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #market-email{
        width:60%;
    }

  }

/*--------Marketing Email-------*/

#marketing-email{
    padding: 1em;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#market-email{
    padding: 0.5em;
    width:30%;
}

.marketing-btn{
    background: #1034A6;
    color:white;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Order in CSS is important! At the moment, the style which comes later in the document overrides the previous setting. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the width didn't increase to 60% on mobile device is because in your css code your first say that `#market-email` should have a width of 60% and just after, you reset it to 30%.

Here is how it should be done to work correctly:

```
#marketing-email{
  padding: 1em;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#market-email{
  padding: 0.5em;
  width:30%;
}

.marketing-btn{
  background: #1034A6;
  color:white;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #market-email{
    width:60%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` part to the end of the page. Because now the second code `#market-email` with `width:30%;` rewriting your `@media` rule.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, styles which come later in the document override earlier ones. Therefore the most specific @media query **must** always come last in the document.

At the moment, `width: 30%;` is applied to all screen sizes **and** comes later in the document, therefore overriding the earlier style of `width: 60%;`.

The solution is simply to change the position of the `@media` query within your CSS:

```css
#marketing-email {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#market-email {
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 30%;
}

.marketing-btn {
  background: #1034A6;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
}


/* Media query comes after other styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #market-email {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```